# Waypoints.js: check if element is in view on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

How would one check if the element is in view with waypoints.js on initial page load or is it not possible?

It seems that you can only attach functionality to events that are triggered on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Waypoints.js` checks the position of the tracked elements upon initialization too, not just when a scroll event happens. With that being said, the only thing you have to do is to observe if an element is above the bottom of the viewport. With waypoints, that can be achieved by setting the [`offset`](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/) parameter to `100%`. This way, the handler function will be called upon pageload if the element in question is in the viewport.

Below is a working example with two initialized waypoint objects.

```js
var waypoint1 = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
    handler: function(direction) {
        console.log('#waypoint in viewport – NO OFFSET');
    }
});

var waypoint2 = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
    offset: '100%',
    handler: function(direction) {
        console.log('#waypoint with OFFSET: 100% in viewport');
    }
});
```

```css
#placeholder {
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #d4cdc3;
}

#waypoint {
    background-color: #d5d0cd;
}

#bottom {
    height: 200vh;
    background-color: #a2a392;
}
```

```html
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<div id="waypoint">[Test content]</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/noframework.waypoints.min.js"></script>
```